# How do I return an SQL query result as custom variable in a template?

Tags: 8, hooks, paragraphs

Is there any way to pass a SQL result with using hook in .theme file? My scenario is following: I have a paragraphs module's view in which I've need of all nodes from content type News to iterate and show by taxonomy term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add variables using a `hook_preprocess_THEME()` function. For example, if you are trying to add a variable to the `page.html.twig` template, the theme hook is `page`. So you would use the following:

```
function hook_preprocess_page(&$vars)
{
  // Add your result to the $vars array:
  $vars['some_variable'] = db_query('SELECT something FROM {some_table} WHERE some_column = :some_value', [':some_value' => 'some value'])->fetchField();
}
```

Because you've added `some_variable` to the `$vars` array, `some_variable` will be available in your template.

Comment: thanks for the reply, appreciated. My subtheme is called **rental_subtheme** and in .theme I have the following:


`function rental_subtheme_page_preprocess(&$vars)`
`{`
  `$vars['some_variable'] = 'text value'; `
`}`



and in paragraph--news-slider.html.twig {{ some_variable }} and nothing is printed. What I'm missing?

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake in my post, but even so, you were preprocessing the wrong theme. The THEME is `paragraph`, so your function needs to be `rental_subtheme_preprocess_paragraph()`